# iOS Simulator failed to install the application - nothing has worked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I been trying to figure out the problem for this and cannot figure it out. Every time I run my Xcode project in the simulator I get an iOS Simulator failed to install the application error. I have tried resetting the content and settings in the simulator and that has not worked. I have tried running other projects in the simulator and they work fine. One thing I did do right before it stopped working was add a font into the plist. I am not sure if that is the problem but here is my current plist (maybe i accidentally deleted something?):
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I was missing the `Executable file` Thanks!